# How will the fall of the UK Pound impact purchasing my first property?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

Since the UK's Brexit vote in June, the pound has fallen sharply in value and with more details coming to light about when article 50 will be implemented we have seen even further decline.

With this sort of instability I am starting to think about my current situation. As the title suggests I have initiated the process of purchasing my first property, the bank are offering me a FRM @ 1.95% for 2years, nothing legally binding has been signed as of yet with my solicitors, however it’s getting to that point.

My question is how will further decline of the pound impact this purchase moving forward in terms of interest rates and housing prices?

PS: This is my first question on stack exchange so apologies in advance for any issues with my question.

Comment: So you are paying in GBP, so why are you worried about it affecting it. You have decided on a price and that is what you will pay. Unless you are converting from some other currency into GBP, there isn't going to be any effects on your house purchase. Your query is at this moment too much opinion based. Nobody knows for sure what will happen.

Comment: Agreed that these changes to the market won’t impact my initial purchase of the property and that no one really knows what’s going to happen, like most things in life. What I was looking for is potential outcomes/scenarios moving forward that may arise from a diminished pound and impact property prices & rates especially outwidth FRM

Comment: No direct impact but if the pound falls it can lead to inflation as imports cost more.  This may prompt the Bank of England to increase interest rates and that would affect your mortgage repayments.

Comment: The GBP has been falling since mid-2014, Brexit has just helped it continue its falls.

Comment: Just as Victor says, it's a total myth (it's "newspaper intelligence") that "Brexit" has "caused" the pound to fall.

Comment: as @davidjwest says; BUT a falling currency can drastically spur manufacturing and the economy; could result in a huge spike in home prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get the ball rolling, here's an answer:

it won't affect you in the slightest.

1. The pound happened to be tumbling anyway.  (If you read "in the papers" that Brexit is "making the pound fall", that's as valuable as anything else you've ever read in the papers.)
2. Currencies go up and down drastically all the time, and there's nothing you can do about it. We by fluke once bought a house in Australia when that currency was very low; over the next couple years the currency basically doubled (I mean per the USD) and we happened to sell it; we made a 1/2 million measured in USD. Just a fluke. I've had the opposite happen on other occasions over the decades. But...
3. Currency changes mean absolutely nothing if you're in that country. The example from (2) was only relevant because we happened to be moving in and out of Aus. My various Australian friends didn't even notice that their dollar went from .5 to 1 in terms of USD (how could it matter to them?)
4. All sorts of things drastically affect the **general economy** of a given country. (Indeed, note that a *falling* currency is often seen as a very *good* thing for a given nation's economy: conspiracy theorists in the states are forever complaining that ) Nobody has the slightest clue if "Brexit" will be good bad or indifferent for the UK. Anything could happen. It could be the beginning of an **incredible period of growth** for the UK (after all, why does Brussels not want your country to leave - goodwill?) and your house could triple in value in a year. Or, your house price could tumble to half in a year. **Nobody has the slightest clue, whatsoever** about the effects on the "economy" of a country going forward, of various inputs.

Comment: In the Netherlands Brexit left the news after a few days or so, saying Europe is "panicked senseless" makes your answer seems a lot less believable than whatever newspapers say.

Comment: hi Rem - was just some flowery-humorous speech; not a big deal.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote ?

Comment: @DumbCoder as if the downvoter that did not regard to leave a comment when he downvoted would come back to answer. Sometimes this kind of thing happen randomly, maybe people that don't like Australia come and downvote from a google search. The answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

There are two impacts: First, if the pound is dropping, then buying houses becomes cheaper for foreign investors, so they will tend to buy more houses as investments, which will drive house prices up. Second, in theory you might be able to get a mortgage in a foreign country, let's say in Euro, and you might hope that over the next few years the pound would go up again, and the Euros that you owe the foreign bank become worth less.